# Configure Jenkins for LDAP failover

Tags: ldap, failover, jenkins

I was wondering if anyone has successfully configured Jenkins with two LDAP servers so if one server fails, it will query the other server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [No.](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-JENKINS-16443-Multiple-LDAP-server-td4652423.html)

There's no way to configure a secondary LDAP server for Jenkins. You can semi-automate failover by using DNS entries (change the A record if the server goes down) or do HA with an LDAP server on its own.

Comment: I think this answer may be outdated. See the ldap plugin documentation at: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-Server  "As of version 1.6, you can specify a list of servers separated by whitespace to provide a fallback if the first server is unavailable..."

Comment: Ironically, the version 1.6 was apparently release a mere 2 weeks after the answer was posted. Looks like someone couldn't live with the limitation...